# Does 'listunspent' work for any address is `txindex=1`?

Tags: bitcoin-core, listunspent, txindex

The [`listunspent`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listunspent.html) Bitcoin Core RPC method by default works only for addresses loaded in the wallet.  Does it work for *any* address if the node has full index (`txindex=1`)?

(Technically it could I think, but since this is a 'wallet' RPC, it may be restricted.)

Answer (score 2):

Correct, this is a wallet RPC, so it only deals with outputs belonging to the wallet.

If you want to query the entire unspent transaction output set, you can use the `scantxoutset` RPC. It doesn't even depend on `txindex=1`.

Comment: I have not considered `scantxoutset`, because it is marked experimental. It works, but I find it quite slow.

Comment: It's slow because it scans through the entire UTXO set, which is currently a few gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin Core Wallet tracks addresses associated with its own keys. `listunspent` is a *wallet* RPC that refers to the wallet data only.
Beyond the wallet's tracking of its own data, Bitcoin Core does not have functionality to keep an address index regardless of whether `txindex` is used or not. I surmise that address tracking was never prioritized by a Bitcoin Core contributor (or even pushed back upon by others) due to the intended single-use nature of addresses.

If you want to keep track of UTXOs per address you may want to look into blockchain explorer projects such as *esplora* or *mempool.space*.