# Obtaining balance/UTXOs of an address from Bitcoin Core, blockbook, or some other solution

Tags: bitcoin-core, lightning-network, balance, utxo-set, scantxoutset

In my application I would like to obtain the balance and UTXO set of some Bitcoin addresses. I'm primarily looking to achieve this using a full node (Bitcoin Core, RPC), but I am also open to other solutions. I run my own node.

Here are the solutions I have considered:

1. Using `scantxoutset` RPC command. This works with any address, returns both UTXOs and total balance. However, it is rather *slow* (for testnet it is on the order of 1 minute, not sure on mainnet). Another disadvantage is that it does not show unconfirmed transactions.
2. Using `listunspent` RPC command. Unfortunately this works only with addresses that are loaded in the wallet of the node, so not with any addresses.
3. Using an external explorer site/API. This is not a good solution due to concerns about availability, trust (source of truth), and access (permissions, rate limits).
4. Using `blockbook` on top of the BTC node (e.g. `api/v2/utxo/<address>`). This seems to be a good solution, but it requires an extra piece of software.

Eventually a notification solution for new transactions to a set of addresses would be also nice, but polling is a workable solution (e.g. every 10 secs, the set of addresses is typically small).

*I would appreciate any other suggestions regarding how to achieve this with a full node, or involving some other available software.*

I'm also curious how Lightning node implementations solve this, as they probably need very similar functionality (LND, C-lightning, LDK).

I include here for reference:

- links to RPC commands
  [scantxoutset](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/scantxoutset.html)
  [listunspent](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listunspent.html)
- [Blockbook](https://github.com/trezor/blockbook) and its [API](https://github.com/trezor/blockbook/blob/master/docs/api.md)
- and a [previous question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116058/does-listunspent-work-for-any-address-is-txindex-1) of mine regarding `listunspents` command

Comment: Did you see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116175/101498?

Comment: No, I haven't, thanks for referencing.

Comment: Using an `Electrum` server is also another good solution for number 4.